# Can I keep my family in Germany and work in Finland on a work permit?

Tags: germany, family, working, finland

I have a residence permit (not a blue card) of Germany until January 2018, and the Rathaus has given me a *Fiktionsbescheinigung* until May 2018, waiting for me to submit a new contract.

Now I have a new contract in Finland and I need to work there from February, but because of school, I will move my family only after July 2018. Is it possible to keep the family in Germany and work in Finland? Will the Rathaus allow keeping the family in Germany until then?

Comment: You should better ask at the Rathaus explaining them your situation and not random people on the internet.

Comment: What is your nationality?